# GWT DataGrid Selection Handler

Tags: forms, gwt, datagrid, selection, handler

I have a DataGrid, and I want to get the selected row when it is clicked:
I want to get its content and its index.
I have some sort of a form under the DataGrid, and when one row is selected, the form will be filled with the data in the selected row above!
Then when I click a button a DialogBox should be shown with the data in the selected row!

I have searched but there is no clear explanation about how to do it.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [API of the Gwt DataGrid](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html), there is one example on how to use GWT DataGrid and `selection model`.

In that example:

```
// Add a selection model to handle user selection. 


final SingleSelectionModel<Contact> selectionModel =
                                           new SingleSelectionModel<Contact();
table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel); 
selectionModel. addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
 public void onSelectionChange( SelectionChangeEvent event) { 
 Contact selected = selectionModel. getSelectedObject();
 if (selected != null) {
 Window.alert("You selected: " + selected.name); }
 } });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DataGrid table = new DataGrid();

final SingleSelectionModel<Contact> selectionModel =
                                           new SingleSelectionModel<Contact>();
table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel); 

Button clickBtn = new Button("Click Button");
clickBtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
Contact selectedContact = ((SingleSelectionModel)table.getSelectionModel()).getSelectedRecord();
setDataInForm(selectedContact);
});
```